# 'video' is not defined Adding YouTube Comment In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to add a comment on a youtube video using youtube.commentThreads().insert,
and I can't figure out why this is happening:

> videoId": video,
> NameError: name 'video' is not defined

This happens after I entered my Google authentication key
here's my code:

```
import os

import requests
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.search().list(
        part="id",
        maxResults=3,
        regionCode="US",
        relevanceLanguage="en",
        type="video",
        videoCategoryId="20"
    )

    youtube.commentThreads().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
            "snippet": {
                "videoId": video,
                "topLevelComment": {
                    "snippet": {
                        "textOriginal": text
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    )
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)
    print ("comment added")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Where is that you're defining the `video` variable (that you then pass on to the `CommentThreads.insert` API endpoint through its request parameter `videoId`)? You need to have `video` (and `videoId` for that matter) set to the ID of the video of your interest.

Comment: @stvar, the script searches for the videos, and then inserts a comment. I've just missed out the comment to add in this.